# How to calculate a sum over a column in gnuplot?

Tags: awk, sum, gnuplot

For the file:

```
#file1
1  3
2  2
3  6
4  5
5  1
```

I want to plot a distribution function of the second column with gnuplot. So I try to find the sum of all values in the column 2. I have not find a solution to this problem.   Could you give some suggestion to calculate the sum of a column in gnuplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for awk. Check `help stats`.

```
stats "file1" u 2

print STATS_sum
```

Once you've done `stats` you can type `show var STATS` and see a lot of more variables which have been calculated.

**Addition:**
@jiadong, as I said before, there is no need for awk to normalize a column.

**Code:**

```
### normalize a column
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#file1
1  3
2  2
3  6
4  5
5  1
EOD

stats $Data u 2 nooutput

plot $Data u 1:($2/STATS_sum) w lp pt 7 ti sprintf("\nnormalized 2nd column\nTotal sum: %g",STATS_sum)

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have a rolling sum, as a standalone script

```
$ awk '{print $0,s+=$2}' file

1  3 3
2  2 5
3  6 11
4  5 16
5  1 17
```

with gnuplot, I guess the syntax is

```
plot "<awk '{print $0,s+=$2}' file"
```

just get the total

```
...   awk '{s+=$2} END{print s}' file
```

however not sure how you're going to plot a single number.

to normalize the column

```
...   awk 'NR==FNR{s+=$2; next} {print $1,(s?$2/s:$2))' file file
```

Comment: Thanks but I need is just need the total sum of all values, that is 17 for this file.  Is it possible to implement with awk in gnuplot?

Comment: Because I want to normalize the second column, so I try to generate eg.,  ($2/sum_of_2nd_col). In other words, I am trying to generate an array like $2/(sum_of_2nd_col) in gnuplot with awk.  I do not know how it can be implemented in a gnuplot command (with help of awk or others).